# связка MySQL и MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

В проекте используются 2 базы данных. Одна — это сайт (MySQL) с пользователями, вторая (MSSQL) это база данных с разными данными.

Нужно, чтобы пользователи в соответствии с правами на сайте (MySQL) могли редактировать или добавлять некоторые данные в MSSQL.

Вопросы:

1) такое взаимодействие возможно?

2) Если на сайте 500 пользователей, могут ли они все работать в таком режиме?

3) Есть пользователи модераторы и обычные, модератор должен править все данные, а пользователь только некоторые, так можно?

Я не очень понимаю этот момент... Буду признателен за ответы.

Comment: 1 - да, 2 - да, 3 - да.

Comment: Можно еще уточнить один момент. Я знаю, что расширенная лицензия на использование MSSQL со множественностью пользователей стоит немалых денег. Будет ли в такой реализации этот момент, или количество пользователей MSSQL будет по сути 1, - сайт.

Comment: @Евгений В web приложениях в большинстве случаев коннект к базе происходит под одним пользователем. А все права доступа, так же как и проверку паролей организуют своими средствами, по своим таблицам

Comment: Да, если вас волнует лицензионность, то по правилам MS лицензия должна быть на всех 500 пользователей. А если их число заранее неизвестно и потенциально неограничено, то нужна будет процессорная лицензия (которая стоит еще более немалых денег). Ну или обходитесь бесплатным MSSQL Express с его ограничениями.